# it's possible create a new type using a types from another interface? Typescript

Tags: typescript

It might look a bit confusing, but basically I have the following interface:

```
interface ITest {
    0: number;
    1: string;
    2: boolean;
    3: string;
    4: string;
    5: Date;
    6: string;
    7: boolean;
    8: string;
    9: string;
    10: number;
}
```

And I wanted to create a type based on her values ​​dynamically. That is, the typing would look like this:

```
type ValueFromITest = number|string|Date|boolean
```

I tried to use some [ts-essentials](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials) functions but I didn't find anything that helps me up

Comment: It seems like you probably want a tuple type, rather than an interface with numeric keys.

Comment: It would just be an example, disregard the any, I'll get it out of there

Comment: `ITest[keyof ITest]` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4CwAUMqcgAwBcyIArgLYBG0A3MWcgIzU5SgDmbEmQBM1RgHsJAGwhwQQjgGYeYPiEHsyAFlXrNw0gFZqAETiRFZAGx6BV0gHZxU2fIfIAHHY0eAnD4GHJxUNAzMUEIAvsTEYACeAA4oAGpw0rQQAGJQEvQY2LgAvGiYOADaANYQ8RIwpYUAukA

Comment: exactly what i needed thank you very much Ugur Eren!
If possible, write an answer so I can mark it as accepted